# Execution ARN of Sync Express Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I have an Express Step Function Workflow created.
I am executing it using the API [StartSyncExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartSyncExecution.html).
In its input, I am providing the `name` of the execution. But the `executionArn` I am receiving in the response is different from the provided value for the `name`: it has a random string appended to the value. (This is minus the state machine arn from the execution arn in its beginning)

What is the expectation with the execution arn of express workflows that are run syncronously. I did not find any documentation on this.

Comment: Not sure but the response seems like `name` is empty. Did you send `name` in API properly?

Comment: Yes. It complies with the constraints.
But the question is about ```executionArn``` in the response. I am not checking for ```name``` in the response.

Answer (score 2):

AWS does append a random string to the user-provided execution name to manage all executions of an express step function.

Since the express step functions are not idempotent, they trigger execution for every request without checking if an execution with the same execution name already exists. But a client can still try to execute a machine with the same execution name over and over.
So they append a random string to the name to distinguish them.